# Create an array of even numbers from 2 to 20.Then using for loop and append function, insert numbers divisible by 7 from 30 to 50 to that array

Tags: python, arrays

Create an array of even numbers from 2 to 20.
Then using for loop and append() function, insert all the numbers divisible by 7 from 30 to 50 to that array.

```
from array import *

for i in array('b',[x for x in range(2,21,2)]):
  for c in array('b',[x for x in range(35,51,7)]):

my_ar = i.append(c)

print(my_ar)
```

Comment: What's the issue here?  What output are you getting versus the output you want?

Comment: Also, check your indentation.  Where should the `my_ar = i.append(c)` line be located?  Are you sure you want the 2nd `for` loop _inside_ the 1st?

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer Homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Also also, why are you using `array()`?  Why are you doing `x for x in range()`?  You can just loop over `range()` directly.  `for i in range(35, 51, 7):`.

Answer (score 1):

The first requirement doesn't specify a loop so you can directly create a list from range.
For the second part you want to append to your previous list within your loop.

```
my_ar = list(range(2, 21, 2))
for num in range(35, 51, 7):
    my_ar.append(num)
```

Result

```
>>> my_ar
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 35, 42, 49]
```

If your requirement is to indeed use the `array` module, then similar approach

```
from array import array
my_arr = array('i', list(range(2, 21, 2)))
for num in range(35, 51, 7):
    my_arr.append(num)
```

Result

```
>>> my_arr
array('i', [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 35, 42, 49])
```

Comment: thank you so much it was very helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others. I don't see the need to use the `array` module. But this can be done without a loop using list addition:

```
list(range(2, 21, 2)) + list(range(35, 51, 7))
```

---

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 35, 42, 49]
```